# Issue with sheets api grabbing small exponent value (e.g. e-13) when writing to an email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working on/modifying a script for my workplace that grabs values from a reconciliation sheet and sends it in an email along with a PDF version of that sheet. Usually, it works fine, however occasionally when the value for over/short (a value that is the result of a sheets formula) is $0.00 it grabs a tiny exponent value (i.e. $9.952671286e-13) instead of zero. Any idea as to why this happening/what I can do to prevent this from happening in the future. (I can provide more information if need be :) )

Here is the code:

```
//The Code below was written by Jason Huang, and was modified by Graham Radtke
function emailPDF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var ovsh = spreadsheet.getRange('K9:L9').getValue();
  //ovsh = Number(ovsh);
  if(ovsh != 0){
    if(!showAlert()){
      return 0;
    }
  }
  
  var blob = _getAsBlob(spreadsheet.getUrl(), currentSheet)
  
  // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  var email = "email@email.com"; 
  
  // Subject of email message
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), '0' , "MM/dd/yyyy");
  
  var subject = "EOD Report:  " + curDate + " " + spreadsheet.getRange('E2:F2').getValue();
  
  // Email Body can  be HTML too
  var body = 'Notes from ' + curDate + ' on ' + spreadsheet.getRange('E2:F2').getValue() + ': \n' + spreadsheet.getRange('G11:K19').getValue();
  
  blob.setName(curDate + '_' + spreadsheet.getRange('E2:F2').getValue() + ".pdf");
  
  var issues = '<br>';
  
  for(var i = 22; i < currentSheet.getLastRow() + 1; i++){
    for(var j = 7; j < currentSheet.getLastColumn() + 1; j += 2){
      if(currentSheet.getRange(i,j,1,2).getValue() != ''){
        issues += currentSheet.getRange(i,j,1,2).getValue() + ' | ';
      }
    }
    issues += '<br>';
  }
  
  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: 'Notes from ' + curDate + ' on ' + spreadsheet.getRange('E2:F2').getValue() + ':<br>' + spreadsheet.getRange('G11:L19').getValue() 
      + '<br> Cash over/short: $' + spreadsheet.getRange('D21').getValue() + '<br> CC over/short: $' + spreadsheet.getRange('K9:L9').getValue()
      + '<br> Orders with issues: <br> Order # | Issue | Notes |' + issues,
      attachments:[blob]
    });
    return;
}

function _getAsBlob(url, sheet, range) {
  var rangeParam = ''
  var sheetParam = ''
  if (range) {
    rangeParam =
      '&r1=' + (range.getRow() - 1)
      + '&r2=' + range.getLastRow()
      + '&c1=' + (range.getColumn() - 1)
      + '&c2=' + range.getLastColumn()
  }
  if (sheet) {
    sheetParam = '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()
  }
  var exportUrl = url.replace(/\/edit.*$/, '')
      + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
      + '&size=LETTER'
      + '&portrait=true'
      + '&fitw=true'       
      + '&top_margin=0.75'              
      + '&bottom_margin=0.75'          
      + '&left_margin=0.7'             
      + '&right_margin=0.7'           
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'
      + '&pagenum=false'
      + '&gridlines=true'
      + '&fzr=FALSE'      
      + sheetParam
      + rangeParam
      
  Logger.log('exportUrl=' + exportUrl)
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {
    headers: { 
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    },
  })
  
  return response.getBlob()
}
```

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Change `getValue` to `getDisplayValue` when fetching that cell

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Changing from getValue to getDisplayValue fixed my problem, Thank you Marios <3